# i want to write contents of my variable into a file

Tags: python, string, text-files

I have stored the output of my `curl` command into a string variable using Python. and now after this I want to transfer this to a file. Can you please help me in this?

My string variable is as below

```
>>> print result
health status index                      pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.18     5   1    1869483            0    477.9mb        477.9mb 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.17     5   1     632263            0    158.8mb        158.8mb 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.19     5   1    1534771            0    386.9mb        386.9mb
```

1. I want to store this content in a file and
2. extract only `logstash-xxx-2016.05.18` from each line and write only this to another file.

Comment: What have you tried? What format file do you want to save to? And what exactly do you want to write to another file?

Comment: You can just print a string to file using `f.open(file_to_write_to, 'w')` and `f.write(string_to_print)`. See the documentation for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
If you need more specific help, you should ask a more specifc question.

Comment: @shaheen: evryone loves to help, when you show us the code just remember to indent by 4 spaces in the textarea, so it is readable for the world willing to help. And the above two comments are IMO full of good hints already

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i want to store above printed result into text file..f.write(string_to_print) will save whatever string we give to the file, but my requirement is i want to store output of a curl command which i have stored in variable "result" to a file.

Comment: date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y.%m.%d').date()  i have used this in my python code, looks like this doesnt work with python 2.4.3 version. can you please suggest me, what can i use instead of this in  2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

This will write the result to a file called 'write_file.txt' and the stings matching 'logstash-xxx-xxxx.xx.xx' line-by-line to a file called 'write_logs.txt':

```
result = """health status index                      pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.18     5   1    1869483            0    477.9mb        477.9mb 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.17     5   1     632263            0    158.8mb        158.8mb 
yellow open   logstash-xxx-2016.05.19     5   1    1534771            0    386.9mb        386.9mb"""

logs_index = [i for i in range(len(result)) if result.startswith('logstash', i)]

logs = [result[i:i + 23] for i in logs_index]

with open('write_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)

with open('write_logs.txt', 'a') as f:
    for l in logs:
        f.write(l + '\n')
```